# Python list and for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

```
a = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(i)
```

The output of this code is: `0 1 2 3 4 5`

How can I modify my code so that the output will be: `1 2 3 4 5` or only `2 3 4` without changing the values of the `a variable`? I just want to extract some parts of the iteration and not the whole.

Comment: Why `1 2 3 4 5`? Why only `2 3 4`?

Comment: `for i in range(1,6)` and `for i in range(2,5)`. The content of your list is not relevant to the behaviour of your loop; all you're reading from it is the length.

Comment: Hi, in for loop you are not accessing any data from array, do you want to print just 2,3,4 or do you wan to access or print data from array indexes ?

Comment: range(1,len(a)) `1 2 3 4 5 ` range(2,4) `2 3 4 `

Comment: Please try to read and run the latest post below?

Comment: If intention is to print 2,3,4 th elements in array, use "print(a[2:5]". this will print ["c","d","e"].

Comment: I have answered my own question below. I know it's not great, but at least it is what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to extract `1 2 3 4 5` or `2 3 4` in my code without altering the aforementioned array. So what I did was this:

```
a = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
for i in range(len(a)):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    print(i)
```

Output: `1 2 3 4 5` without the `0`

And if I only want to extract `2 3 4` what I did was this:

```
a = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
for i in range(len(a)):
    if i < 2:
        continue
    elif i == 5:
        continue
    print(i)
```

Output: `2 3 4`

Comment: ...seeing this I'm even _more_ confused about what you were trying to accomplish.

Comment: I also have no idea where I will be using this. It's just a thought (or problem) that I've encountered trying to learn this loop.

Comment: There is no reason to iterate over the numbers 0 though `len(a) - 1` if you don't care about 0. Just use `range(1, len(a))`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using slicing:

left to right indexing works as 0 to `len(a)-1`
and right to left is -1 to -len(a)

Syntax is:

```
a[start_index:end_index]
```

Above can give you elements as output then you can apply index function of list to get the index values.

NOTE: This approach will work if you want to extract an intact part of a list. It won't iterate on whole list, instead only on the part you want to extract.

While giving slicing remember `end_index` is not included.

For extracting 1,2,3,4,5:

```
for i in a[1:]:
    print(a.index(i))

#or
```

For extracting 2,3,4:

```
for i in a[2:5]:
    print(a.index(i))
```

Comment: Is this correct? `>>> a[2:5]` 
['c', 'd', 'e']      (that should be 3rd, 4th, 5th items)

Comment: Thanks for correction, i misunderstood the output previously.

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned you are new to this, then let's understand what's happening first then we can modify it according to our requirements.
***for i in range(len(a)):***
The **range()** function is used to generate a sequence of numbers. here,from (0 to len(a)-1) and here len(a)=6
so your for loop is iterating from 0 to 5.
Now if we wanna modify our output say we want 2,3,4
then we can provide an 'if' statement to select any particular subset i.e

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if(i>1) & (i<5):
        print(i)
```

or, you can try slicing if u are comfortable with:
for output as 2,3,4

```
print(a[2:5])
```

remember a[starting:ending+1]